# There are some projects where images need to be saved in a DB, especially in the health sector?

Tags: security, web-applications, storage

Some projects prefer storing images only in DB and some projects prefer only at servers and some store both places ie., DB and Servers. Is there anything measures to be taken from the performance of app, storage and security perspective?